# img element not resizing pushing content out of card

Tags: html, css, responsive

Hey guys so i'm trying to make a responsive image with a img element but the height of the element is not being respected.

I created this example: https://codepen.io/apodacaduron/pen/ExmpzrE?editors=1100

```html
  <div class="container" draggable="true">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://t1.gstatic.com/licensed-image?q=tbn:ANd9GcRXn5Ts02SPH0uXL1hglAYHkimX6Hd36zb1nrqjtJD1C0V7hy4QRqu4ldsT_ukVAeCt6Kx43WK8rGZFMla7uhI" />
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      text content <br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```css
.container {
  background: blue;
  width: 336px;
  height: 383px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 16px;
}

.image {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.image > img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.text {
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}
```

I would like to make the third card exactly like the second one, where if the text grows (green div) the image gets smaller, but i was not able to achieve this using the img element. (THE IMG ELEMENT SHOULD NOT HAVE A FIXED HEIGHT!)

Does somebody know how to do this?

Comment: make container height: auto; and see if you like the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to set the container of img with min width 0 and min height 0

```css
.image {
  min-height: 0;
  min-width: 0;
}

.image > img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.container {
  background: blue;
  width: 336px;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 16px;
}

.image {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.cheat-image {
  background: url('http://t1.gstatic.com/licensed-image?q=tbn:ANd9GcRXn5Ts02SPH0uXL1hglAYHkimX6Hd36zb1nrqjtJD1C0V7hy4QRqu4ldsT_ukVAeCt6Kx43WK8rGZFMla7uhI') no-repeat center center / contain;
}

.image > img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.text {
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="flex">
  <div class="container" draggable="true">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="text">
      text content <br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br />

  <div class="container" draggable="true">
    <div class="image cheat-image"></div>
    <div class="text">
      text contentIf you want to restrict a responsive image to a maximum size, use the max-width property, with a pixel value of your choice. If you want to restrict a responsive image to a maximum size, use the max-width property, with a pixel value of your choice.<br><br><br><br><br><br>
    If you want to restrict a responsive image to a maximum size, use the max-width property, with a pixel value of your choice.</div>
  </div>

  <br />

  <div class="container" draggable="true">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://t1.gstatic.com/licensed-image?q=tbn:ANd9GcRXn5Ts02SPH0uXL1hglAYHkimX6Hd36zb1nrqjtJD1C0V7hy4QRqu4ldsT_ukVAeCt6Kx43WK8rGZFMla7uhI" />
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      text content If you want to restrict a responsive image to a maximum size, use the max-width property, with a pixel value of your choice.If you want to restrict a responsive image to a maximum size, use the max-width property, with a pixel value of your choice.<br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```